# AS3 / Flex 3 Staggered Remoting + Queue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, remoting

I am trying to make a class that staggers the net connections calls by a certain amount to not put too much pressure on my server, and so I don't have a dozen net connectors running around in my code. 
I want a class that I can send a call command to, the class adds the call to the queue, and then about every one second it see if anything is in the queue, and if so calls it. This is what I have so far.

```
package net
{
 import flash.events.TimerEvent;
 import flash.net.NetConnection;
 import flash.net.Responder;
 import flash.utils.Timer;


 public class Server 
 {
  private static var gateway:String = "http://localhost/gateway.php";
  private static var queue:Vector.<ServerNode>
  private static var nc:NetConnection;
  private static var instance:Server = null;
  private static var res:Responder;
  private var timer:Timer;

  public function Server(e:ServerEnforcer) {
   nc = new NetConnection();
   queue = new Vector.<ServerNode>();
   timer = new Timer(1000);
   timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, execCall);
   timer.start();
  }

  public static function getInstance():Server {
   if (instance == null) {
    instance = new Server(new ServerEnforcer);
   }
   return instance;
  }

  private function execCall(e:Event):void {
   if (queue.length > 0) {
    var node:ServerNode = queue.pop();
    nc.call(node.method, node.res, node.args);
   }
  }

  public function call(method:String, success:Function, failure:Function, ...args):void {
   queue.unshift(new ServerNode(method, success, failure, args));
  }

  private function serverFailure(event:Object):void {
   trace("Server Failure : " + event.description);
  }
 }
}
import flash.net.Responder;

class ServerEnforcer { } 

class ServerNode {
 public var method:String;
 public var success:Function;
 public var failure:Function;
 public var args:Array;
 public var res:Responder

 public function ServerNode(_method:String, _success:Function, _failure:Function, _args:Array) {
  method = _method;
  success = _success;
  failure = _failure;
  res = new Responder(success, failure);
  args = _args;
 }
}
```

Now when I call

```
Server.getInstance().call("Fetch.getData", parseAllData, onError)

public function parseAllData(event:Object):void {
    trace("Victory!");
}
public function onError(event:Object):void {
    trace("Error :" + event);
}
```

absolutely nothing happens.  Any idea why or a point in the right direction why this isn't working?

Comment: What exactly does happen? For instance, in debug mode does the program get connected to the server, is it just the returned data thats empty, does your application run at all? At least give that much information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created an instance of the NetConnection, but haven't actually initiated a connection with the server.

In other words,

```
nc.connect(gateway);
```

is missing.

See [NetConnection documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5) for more information on that class.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.